# Как передать FormData на NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

делаю так:

client.js

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('test', 'test');

$.ajax({
    url: '/form',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    success: function ( d ) {
        console.log( d );
    },
    error: function( a, b, c){
      console.log( a );
      console.log( b );
    }
});
```

server.js

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var app = express();
...
app.post('/form', function(req, res) {

  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      console.log('fields:', fields);
  });    
}
```

в логе получаю:

> fields: undefined

почему поля не парсятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому, что в AJAX $.ajax({data:..}); должна передаваться urlencoded data вида
"?test=test" . Тогда бэкэнд будет получать её как инпуты и их значения.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/form',
    data: "test=test",
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    success: function ( d ) {
        console.log( d );
    },
    error: function( a, b, c){
      console.log( a );
      console.log( b );
    }
});
```

А вы передали объект формы.

Comment: Конечно, вы можете в data передавать любые данные, отметив их тип в dataType опции.

Comment: А ещё не проверял, как в вашем случае, но обычную форму можно заюрлэенкодить с помощью jQuery:

 var data =$('#form').serialize();